# Edit and Return Value from Fetch

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch

I'm able to return an array of a self made json page via the getvals() function below. Unfortunately I'm not able to find how to edit the value retrieved and how to return it.

It's my first time using JavaScript, so bear with me please :)

```
function getvals(){
return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/mysteps/default',
{
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
  return responseData;
})
.catch(error => console.warn(error));
}
```

the value retrieved looks like this  :

```
{
"mysteps": [
 {
  "destination": "Death Valley, CA, USA", 
  "duration_text": "2 hours 43 mins", 
  "id": 4, 
  "km": 249.0, 
  "origin": "Bishop, CA, USA", 
  "route_data": "[[-120.483008, 37.303716], [-120.483008, 37.303716]]"
 }, 
 {
  "destination": "merced", 
  "duration_text": "2 hours 9 mins", 
  "id": 5, 
  "km": 210.6, 
  "origin": "San Francisco, CA, USA", 
  "route_data": "[[-118.399663, 37.361368], [-118.399334, 37.36137], 
  [-118.398783, 37.361372], [-118.398282, 37.361379],...
```

I've created code to edit the data the way I want to , I.E. Add each routes to each other to form an itinerary,
but I'm unable to use it :

```
 fetch('/mysteps/' + mysavedtrip).then(function(response) {
     response.json().then(function(data) {
     let optionHTML2 = '';

     for (let mystep of data.mysteps) {
     optionHTML2 += mystep.route_data.replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/, "$1") + ', '
                              }
     optionHTML2 = optionHTML2.slice(0,-2);
     optionHTML2 = "[" + optionHTML2 + "]";
     state_select2.innerHTML = optionHTML2;
     });
   });
```

I can display optionHTML2 and can see that its the output I want, but what I want to do is assign optionHTML2 as a variable that will feed a map in "getcoordidnates"

```
map.on('load', function () {
   map.addLayer({
     "id": "route",
     "type": "line",
     "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": getcoordinates                                     
             }
         }
        },
        "layout": {
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
        "line-color": "#888",
        "line-width": 3
       }
     });
    });
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything in the .then() so the fetch doesn't return you a value.

```
return fetch('/mysteps/' + mysavedtrip).then(function(response) {
  return response.json().then(function(data) {
  let optionHTML2 = '';

  for (let mystep of data.mysteps) {
    optionHTML2 += mystep.route_data.replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/, "$1") + ', '
                          }
    optionHTML2 = optionHTML2.slice(0,-2);
    optionHTML2 = "[" + optionHTML2 + "]";
    state_select2.innerHTML = optionHTML2;
    return optionHTML2;
 });
});
```

After you add the code above to the function getvals(), the function should return a promise with the value of optionHTML2.

So you can use it like that:

```
getvals().then(function(optionHTML2) {
  do what you want with the optionHTML2 here.
})
```

Comment: ooh I see now ! Thanks a ton !